# Plotting partial sums of Taylor Function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I need to plot the partial function:

$T_f(x)=\log 2+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2^kk}(x-2)^k$

for $n=2$,$n=4$ and $n=6$ on the same plot over the interval $[-\frac{1}{2},4]$ and also the maximum difference between $f$ and these partial sums of $T_f$ in the same interval

And i have no idea how to do it...

Comment: So, you have looked at `Table[]`, `Sum[]`, and `Plot[]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
Log[2] + Sum[(-1)^(k + 1) (x - 2)^k/(k 2^k), {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

> Log[x]

Since `Log` is complex or unbounded for non-positive argument, the maximum difference is undefined for `x <= 0`

```
Log /@ {0, -1/4} // InputForm
```

> {-Infinity, I*Pi - Log[4]}

The maximum difference will be arbitrarily large as `x` gets arbitrarily close to `0+`.

```
Clear[f]

f[x_, n_] := Log[2] + Sum[(-1)^(k + 1) (x - 2)^k/(k 2^k), {k, 1, n}]

f[x, Infinity]
```

> Log[x]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[x, n], {n, {2, 4, 6, Infinity}}]], {x, -1/2, 4}, 
  PlotLegends -> {2, 4, 6, Infinity}] // Quiet
```

[image]